# Splitting conditions in equations

Tags: equations

I'm trying to split the condition in a set of equations; see figure.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{align*}
\rho(X,Y)&=1&
\begin{split}
\text{if and only if }\mathbb P(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1\\
\text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with }\alpha>0,
\end{split}\\
\rho(X,Y)&=-1&
\begin{split}
\text{if and only if }\mathbb P(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1\\
\text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with }\alpha<0.
\end{split}
\end{align*}
```

However, the first line of the condition isn't at the same level as the equation. I don't like it how the conditions are aligned.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or what other environment to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please post full documents not fragments, I'd use parbox or aligned

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

a
\begin{align*}
\rho(X,Y)&=1&&
\parbox[t]{5cm}{
if and only if $\mathbb P(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$\\
for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha>0$,}
\\[\jot]
\rho(X,Y)&=-1&&
\parbox[t]{5cm}{if and only if $\mathbb P(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$\\
for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha<0$.}
\end{align*}

or
\begin{align*}
\rho(X,Y)&=1&&
\begin{aligned}[t]\text{if and only if }\mathbb P(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1\\
\text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with }\alpha>0,
\end{aligned}\\[\jot]
\rho(X,Y)&=-1&&
\begin{aligned}[t]\text{if and only if }\mathbb P(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1\\
\text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with }\alpha<0.
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about the `amsmath` environment `cases`? Like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\rho(X,Y)=
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}1 & \text{if and only if $\mathbb{P}(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$}
       \\
       &\text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha >0$,}
\\[4pt]
    -1 & \text{if and only if $\mathbb{P}(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$}
       \\
       &\text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha < 0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Multiline conditions with cases]

If desired, the line spacing between the pair of lines in each two-line condition could be tightened up a bit by using, say, `\\[-2pt]` in place of the first and third instance of `\\`

Comment: Right! (Just forgot I was already in math mode. Edit made.

Answer (score 3):

A variant not mentioned in other answers, which uses `tabular`.

It has the advantage that you don't need to guess the width of the `\parbox` and avoids clumsy `\text` macros. The specifier `@{}l@{}` means one left aligned column with no padding on either side.

With `alignat` you have finer control over the space between the two parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\Pr}{\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}} % probability operator

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\rho(X,Y) &= 1  &\qquad& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                         if and only if $\Pr(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$ \\
                         for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha>0$,
                         \end{tabular}
\\[1ex]
\rho(X,Y) &= -1 &&       \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                         if and only if $\Pr(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$ \\
                         for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha<0$.
                         \end{tabular}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `aligned` environment, with the optional `[t]` argument. Don't forget that `align`  requires  3 ampersands for 2  alignment points. I'd recommend using `alignat{2}` to have control on the horizontal spacing of the two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  ρ(X,Y) & =1 & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t]
  & \text{if and only if }\mathbb P(Y=αX+β)=1\\
  & \text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with }\alpha>0,
  \end{aligned}\\[1ex]
  ρ(X,Y) & =-1 & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t]
  & \text{if and only if }\mathbb P(Y=αX+β)=1\\
  & \text{for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with }\alpha<0.
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you use a `dcases` environment (courtesy of the `mathtools` package) and use `\parbox`es to house the conditioning information.

[image]

If you would rather have the parboxes top-aligned, simply add `[t]` ("top") positioning specifiers:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools}
\let\Pr\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{\mathbb{P}} % probability operator
\begin{document}
\[
\rho(X,Y) =
\begin{dcases} % optional: '[t]' ("top") specifiers for the parboxes
1 & \parbox[t]{5.5cm}{if and only if $\Pr(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$ for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha>0$,}\\[1ex]
-1 & \parbox[t]{5.5cm}{if and only if $\Pr(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$ for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha<0$.}
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you choose the width?

Comment: @egreg - I eyeballed the OP's work and tried 5cm, but that looked a bit too tight. So I selected 5.5cm, and that looked about right. :-) I guess I could have been a bit more systematic and measured the width of `if and only if $\Pr(Y=\alpha X+\beta)=1$`...